# Writing to a list in an external module

Tags: python, list, module

So I'm working on a discord bot that has commands like meme commands, roast commands, etc, and since I'm still learning python I haven't started to work with databases yet and store all the roasts in a separate py file and then import it as a module in the bot file.

I want to create another .py file that imports the list and appends to it instead of me opening the py file and edit it myself... heres the code i've written for now and even though it executes without any errors, the list module does not append.

```
from roasts_list import roast

adder_value = input("What would you like to add? \n")
roast.append(adder_value)
```

the module is the roasts_list and the list name is roast.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating an external python module for storing the list, you can store it in a text file.

```py
adder_value = input("What would you like to add? \n")

#add roasts to the text file

roast_file = open("roast.txt", "a")
roast_file.write(adder_value + "\n") #adds roast to the text file
roast_file.close()

#get roasts

roast_file = open("roast.txt", "r")
roast_list = roast_file.read().splitlines() #returns a list of all roasts in the text file
roast_file.close()
```

Using this method, you can save your roasts in text files, and use them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Devansh. If you go with your approach to save them in e.g. a list variable from a .py file, that would mean that all of your values would only be stored in memory and as soon as the program stops, all values will be lost. If you want to persistently store the values, the easiest way would be to store them in a file.

In addition to Devansh approach above, i would suggest opening the file with its context manager, and adding a try/except to handle if you try getting roasts from the file before it's created, making it a little bit more stable in a running program.

```py
#add roasts to the text file
def add_roast():
    adder_value = input("What would you like to add?  ")
    with open("roast.txt", "a") as roast_file:
        roast_file.write(adder_value + "\n") #adds roast to the text file

#get roasts
def get_roasts():
    try:
        with open("roast.txt", "r") as roast_file:
            return roast_file.read().splitlines()
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print("No roasts exist yet")

add_roast()
print(get_roasts())
```